# Possible recursive or analytical query. Can this be done via SQL or is a Script Required?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Not sure if this is possible or not through a standard query but here is how I would like my data to be.

```
START    END    SETTLE    NEW_SETTLE    CORRECTION_FACT    STORED_SETTLE
1        2      120       NULL          1                  120
2        3      127       119           1.0084             128.0668
3        4      NULL      125           1.0245344          NULL
```

Calculations are done as follows:

```
CORRECTION_FACT
```

Basically, if NEW SETTLE is null or this is Row 1 than correction factor is always 1.  If row > 1 than correction factor is `PREV ROW STORED_SETTLE / NEW_SETTLE`  eg. 120/119

```
STORED_SETTLE
```

This will always be `CORRECTION_FACTOR` * `SETTLE`.  This value is not known until the next row is inserted so there will be times where it is NULL.  Tricky part is that this is dependent on `CORRECTION_FACT` which is also a calculated value and `CORRECTION_FACT` is dependent on `STORED_SETTLE`.

In terms of values that I have, I have `SETTLE, NEW_SETTLE, START` and `END`.  `CORRECTION_FACT` and `STORED_SETTLE` will always have to be calculated.

So the question here is can I do this with some sort of recursive query or analytical function or do I have to write a script to populate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
with T1 as
  (select 1 strt, 2 en, 120  settle, null new_settle from dual union all
   select 2 strt, 3 en, 127  settle, 119  new_settle from dual union all
   select 3 strt, 4 en, null settle, 125  new_settle from dual
  )
select strt
     , en
     , settle
     , new_settle
     , correction_fact
     , stored_settle 
  from t1
  model
   dimension by(row_number() over (order by strt) RowNumber)
   measures(strt, en, settle, new_settle
          , cast(null as number) correction_fact
          , cast(null as number) stored_settle)
   rules automatic order
   (
     correction_fact[1]=1,
     correction_fact[RowNumber>1] = decode(new_settle[cv()], null,
                  1,stored_settle[cv()-1]/new_settle[cv()]),                           
     stored_settle[rownumber]=(correction_fact[cv()]*settle[cv()])
   );
```

Result:

```
  STRT         EN     SETTLE NEW_SETTLE CORRECTION_FACT STORED_SETTLE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------------- -------------
     1          2        120                          1           120
     2          3        127        119      1.00840336    128.067227
     3          4                   125      1.02453782
```